# Can Client Blazor WebAssembly application access local serial port on client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, windows-services, single-page-application, blazor-client-side

How should I access a serial port on a client PC from a webpage in a production environment?

Ideally coded in C# and client Blazor, but any suggestions very welcome. 
Any example applications on the web?

Web Serial API and Javascript option works in Chrome if you enable the experimental option: "Experimental Web Platform features" : Enables experimental Web Platform features that are in development. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android. #enable-experimental-web-platform-features
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=884928

Being experimental precludes use in a production environment till it is formally released (experimental licence must be renewed every 6 weeks, expires in September 2020 and the functionality can be removed by Google at any time.)

So far the only solution I can think of is to create an ASP.NET Core Service application that must be installed on the client and the webpage application must connect to this local API to use the local serial port.

Any technical issues that would prevent this service approach from working? Other approaches I should consider.

The web application will be designed to interface with a central/upper arm blood pressure monitor that outputs large XML (or JSON) results after each measurement. The measurements will be saved into a "cloud" service for research and patient monitoring.

Thank you in advance for suggestions and comments.